# Can't create an external table

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I created a `Synapse SQL Pool` without issues, like the previous that is in production with the same configurations, apparently.

In this new `SQL Pool` when I try to create an external table I receive this error:

Error:

```
Failed to execute query. Error: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)
```

I just revised the firewall rules, configurations and some of Microsoft`s documents without success.

Comment: if you are still facing the issue , please drop an email to azcommunity@microsoft.com with the Subject : "Himanshu" and we can interact to find more on this . The error itself is not veru helpful at ths time .

Comment: What credential are you trying to use? I received this error message when trying to use a SAS token credential instead of a storage account key.